# C code - segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to fix this error for an hour, but still can't figure it out. I get segmentation fault exactly in place, where I don't manipulate with array.

```
int height, width, i=0, j=0;
    char newline;

    scanf("%d %d%c", &height, &width, &newline);

    if(newline != '\n')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    char pole[height][width];
    char nch;

    while(1)
    {
        nch = getchar();

        if(nch == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(nch != '\n')
        {
            pole[i][j] = nch;
            printf("i=%d a j=%d\n", i, j); //for my info, there it still runs
            j++;
        }
        //The end of working piece of code (in last cycle...)
        if(j>= width)
        {
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
        if(i >= height)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start with: `char nch;` -->> `int nch;` And `i` and `j` are used but never defined. (neither are `width` and `hight` )

Comment: Well, for one thing, `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and if I recall correctly, implicitly casting to an `int` as you are doing here will make the `EOF` comparison fail.

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use the debugger (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: oh sorry, it`s not whole code, it's just part of code, variables are declared.

Comment: you can not declare array of runtime size. `char pole[height][width];`

Comment: `koleje.c:94:16: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
               ^
koleje.c:94:29: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
                            ^
2 warnings generated. ` 
this is from compilation. 
Tried to change initialization of array to pole[500][500], did`t help.

Comment: oh, well, changing initialization of array seems to work, thanks!

Comment: "*I get segmentation fault exactly in place ...*" and this is exaclty which line, please?

Comment: @Swanand: Of course you can! It's called VLA. You can even _define_ it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing `i` and `j`.  Set both to 0 before entering the `while` loop.

Comment: sorry, I should upload whole code. I initialize them.